# Require none or both fields with Zod

Tags: typescript, zod

I have the properties `startDate` and `endDate` in a Zod schema. I'd like to verify that either:

- None of them are set
- Both of them are set

I.e. if only `startDate` or only `endDate` is set, parsing will fail.

The schema looks like:

```
export const MediumSchema = z.object({
    ImageSetID: z.number().int().positive(),
    ...
    CampaignStartDate: z.date().nullable(),
    CampaignEndDate: z.date().nullable(),
    Url: z.string().url().transform((url) => new URL(url)),
    CDNUrl: z.string().url().transform((url) => new URL(url))
});
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`union`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#unions) or the built in `or` method to union the two possible schemas you expect. For example:

```js
import { z } from 'zod';

const schema = z.object({
  startDate: z.date(),
  endDate: z.date(),
});

const schemaBothUndefined = z.object({
  startDate: z.undefined(),
  endDate: z.undefined(),
});

const bothOrNeither = schema.or(schemaBothUndefined);

console.log(bothOrNeither.safeParse({})); // success
console.log(bothOrNeither.safeParse({
  startDate: new Date(),
  endDate: new Date(),
})); // success
console.log(bothOrNeither.safeParse({
  startDate: new Date(),
})); // failure
```

### Edit: Further details when part of a larger schema

If the schema is to be used as part of a larger schema you can use [`and`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#intersections) for those fields like:

```js
import { z } from "zod";

const startAndEnd = z.object({
  CampaignStartDate: z.date(),
  CampaignEndDate: z.date(),
});
const neitherStartNorEnd = z.object({
  CampaignStartDate: z.undefined(),
  CampaignEndDate: z.undefined(),
});

const CampaignDates = startAndEnd.or(neitherStartNorEnd);

export const MediumSchema = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
}).and(CampaignDates);

console.log(MediumSchema.safeParse({ id: '11' })); // success 
console.log(MediumSchema.safeParse({ 
  id: '11',
  CampaignStartDate: new Date(),
  CampaignEndDate: new Date()
})); // Success
console.log(MediumSchema.safeParse({ 
  id: '11',
  CampaignEndDate: new Date()
})); // Failure
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! `startDate` and `endDate` is part of a bigger schema. How do I apply this in a bigger schema? See edited question with schema above.

Comment: I've added a bit more explanation in response to your edits. Hope this helps!

Comment: Works just as intended. You've saved me again, thanks!

Comment: amazing!!!!!!!!!